# Xcode - Visually identify custom views in interface builder / storyboard

Tags: xcode, uiview, interface-builder, storyboard

If you build a custom UIView, and integrate it inside of a parent view/view controller in interface builder, the graphical element representing your custom view is invisible, if you don't specify a background color (I don't).

Is there any way, solely during development, to identify different custom views? Any hacks/tricks to distinguish them?

The closest I could come up with is setting the background color in IB, then removing the background in the implementation of the custom view.

Comment: You might want to look at a tool like [Reveal](http://revealapp.com/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Bounds Rectangles

You might find bounds rectangles useful.  You can turn them on by going to the menu bar and choosing Editor > Canvas > Show Bounds Rectangles.

Here's an example.  I have a view (a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass) laid out in a nib.  It has a single-line label, a two-line  label, and a custom subview.  The custom subview itself contains a smaller custom subview. Here's the nib with bounds rectangles off:

[image: without bounds rectangles]

Here's the same nib with bounds rectangles on:

[image: with bounds rectangles]

### Background Color Override

Here's another technique that builds on the idea of setting the background color.  This technique requires your deployment target to be iOS 5.0 or later.

As you described, set the background color to make the view visible in the nib:

[image: background color]

Then switch to the Identity Inspector and add `backgroundColor` in the User Defined Runtime Attributes section.  Set it to the background color you want the view to have at runtime.  For example, if you want it to be white at runtime:

[image: backgroundColor in user defined runtime attributes]

If you want the background color to be clear, you can set `backgroundColor` to a color with opacity 0, or you can set it to “Nil” instead of any color:

[image: backgroundColor set to Nil]

Comment: Updated with another approach.

Comment: Using the "Show Bounds Rectangle" option now this makes everything a lot easier Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

That approach of setting the background color in Interface Builder, but resetting it in code is a simple, but effective technique. Two refinements:

1. If you have multiple custom views on a single storyboard scene, you can save yourself from having to programmatically clear the background color for all of them individually by using `IBOutletCollection`. So, in Interface Builder, give them all background colors and then add all of your custom views for a given scene to a collection. You then can set the background color for all of them in a single statement. So, for example, if you have a dozen controls on one scene all in a single `IBOutletCollection` is named `viewsCollection`:

   ```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIView) NSArray *viewsCollection;
   ```

   you can clear the background color of all of them in a single statement:

   ```
   [self.viewsCollection setValue:[UIColor clearColor] forKey:@"backgroundColor"];
   ```
2. You can also make the identification of your custom views in Interface Builder a little easier by setting the "Label" in the "Document" properties on the "Identity inspector":

   [image: label]

   Once you've done that, when you look at the document outline in the left side of the main panel, you'll see your labels show up:

   [image: document outline]

   Then, using the document outline makes it easier to identify your individual views in the scene. You can use a random label like I did here, or you could use the name of your custom view class, or whatever.